# swiftUI: possible to have background color ignore safe zone and content adhere to safe zone?

Tags: swiftui

I want to put `.edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)` on a `VStack` so that the background color covers the whole view.

```
VStack {
    Text("Foo")
}
.edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
.background(Color.red)
```

[image]

This covers the whole view in the background color, which is the behavior I want, but the Text is now also ignoring the safe zones.  Is there a better way to have a background cover the entire view without sacrificing the safe zone coverage for the inner content?

Comment: `.edgesIgnoringSafeArea()` is deprecated. You should use `.ignoresSafeArea()`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You only want the `Color` to extend into the safe area, so only put `ignoresSafeArea` on the `Color`. Also, if you're using iOS 14+, you should use [`ignoresSafeArea(_:edges:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/text/ignoressafearea(_:edges:)) instead of the deprecated [`edgesIgnoringSafeArea(_:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/menu/edgesignoringsafearea(_:)) as [West1 said](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67796196/swiftui-possible-to-have-background-color-ignore-safe-zone-and-content-adhere-t/67796324#comment119832776_67796196).

```
VStack {
    Text("Foo")
}
.background(
    Color.red.ignoresSafeArea()
)
```

---

Full example:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            HStack {
                Text("Foo")
                Spacer()
            }
            Spacer()
        }
        .background(
            Color.red.ignoresSafeArea() /// `edgesIgnoringSafeArea` is deprecated
        )
    }
}
```

Result:

[image: Red background extends into safe area, but text doesn't]

Comment: beautiful, thanks!  I didn't know you can use modifiers on the Color like that

Comment: @mitchellOcavoos that's because view modifiers work on Views, and SwiftUI's `Color` is actually a View. Just like `VStack`, `Text`, `Rectangle`, etc.